# Why Action Settings doesn't show while changing Device?

Tags: android, android-layout

Why I can't see action settings in action bar in Samsung Mini S3 after simple hello world compilation where it shows up in Nexus 7. Is it depend on somehow in app theme the one I am using? I tried to change app theme but it looks like it always takes Nexus S layout even i select Samsung Mini Display size. Any idea ?

PS. I also can't select Samsung Mini Display size 800*480 where in ADB i have option 480*800

Comment: do you mean the overflow menu?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default action bar which gets created in a new android application you will of course not see the overflow menu on the samsung mini S3 because if i am not mistaken then s3 mini has a hard button on the left which will open up the overflow menu for you